# Let and Block-scoped declarations problem with npm installing

Tags: software-installation, npm

I am using **Ubuntu 16.04**.

After installing npm, it's not working as intended. I am getting error like the following:

`$ npm -v
/home/MYUSERNAME/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:85
let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3`

Here are the sources I tried to install/reinstall npm from:

1. [nodesource](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-ubuntu/)
2. [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)
3. [rosehosting](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-npm-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

I know in Ubuntu 16.04, I need to **alias** */usr/bin/nodejs* as */usr/bin/node* to make npm work. After doing so, I can check the node version as the following picture shows.

`$ node --version
 v4.2.6`

But I still cannot use npm.
I have searched and found some similar [github issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/264) link, that seems to have been resolved, but couldn't understand how they solve it.

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I bypassed the problem by installing npm using anaconda. More specifically from this site: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nodejs